# How to include extra data fields in FCM payload (iOS)?

Tags: python, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a payload that specifies a sound to play upon the notification on the device, so that the payload looks like this:

```
{
    "to":"myToken",
    "notification":{
        "title":"new message",
        "body":"Hello World!",
        "sound":"specifiedSound.caf",
    }
}
```

However, in my python script, when I tried to add an extra field to the notification it says that `sound` is an unexpected argument:

```
message = messaging.Message(
        notification = messaging.Notification(
            title = "Title",
            body = "Body",
            sound = "specifiedSound.caf"                <-- unexpected argument
        ),
        token = "myToken"
    )

    # Send message
    response = messaging.send(message)
    print("Successfully sent message:", response)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joelin/Documents/GitHub/taiwanEEW-Server/eewPush.py", line 53, in <module>
    send_data("3", 3)
  File "/Users/joelin/Documents/GitHub/taiwanEEW-Server/eewPush.py", line 36, in send_data
    notification = messaging.Notification(
TypeError: Notification.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sound'
```

I also tried this but still doesn't work

```
notification = messaging.Notification(
            title = "Title",
            body = "Body"
        ),
        data = {
            "sound":"soundtest"
        }
...
```

```
    return _get_messaging_service(app).send(message, dry_run)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 355, in send
    raise self._handle_fcm_error(error)
firebase_admin.exceptions.InvalidArgumentError: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

I've tried my best searching for the answer, sorry if this is a duplicate question, thank you so much!